How to securely expose the app version from package.json using ES Modules?
I'm currently using ESM in my TypeScript + Next.js project, and I want to log the application version from my package.json file to the client console.
Here is the code snippet I'm using in a global react context:
// file: hooks/global-context.tsx
import packageJson from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };

if (environment !== 'production') {
  console.log(`Version: ${packageJson.version} - Environment: ${environment}`);
}

This works just fine, but I'm concerned about security risks. Since I'm importing the entire package.json file as a json, it could potentially expose sensitive information, such as all the dependencies and their versions, to anyone who could access this code.
My questions are:

How can I safely log only the version from package.json without exposing other information?
Are there best practices or alternative approaches to achieve this securely?

Another thing I had in mind, is to import the "packageJson" in a separate file, and then export only the ‘packageJson.version’:
// file: utils/appVersion.ts
import packageJson from 'package.json' assert { type: 'json' };
export const appVersion = packageJson.version;

But I'm not sure if it's any different?
Note: I can't make use of environment variables for this.
Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Neither your code nor your package.json should contain any sensitive information. What exactly are you worried about?

What bundling tool is next.js using for this? Did you look at the compiler output?

I'm worried about giving access to the user to see what "package.json" file has, for example, my dependencies and its versions, giving access to someone to search for current known vulnerabilities for a specific dependency with that specific version.
My bundling tool is Webpack 5 (default for Next v12.1.0) and compiler is Babel.
I didn't thought about looking into the compiler output, should I build the app (npm run build) to do that? Where should I look?
